# CSS cuting image in absolute block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to cut image with absolute block. I want to hide right image with (red line) left column height.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micchaleq/82ov0e3t/23/)

```css
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.box {
    position: relative;  
}

.border {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.inside {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;      
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row border">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/nature/" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 relative">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="inside">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/1000/nature/" class="img-responsive"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I can't help but wonder if you're asking for the opposite of what the answerers think you're asking. In that case, it would be https://jsfiddle.net/82ov0e3t/30/

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/82ov0e3t/28/

```
.border{ bordeR: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To cut the right image in the height of the left image, use this js in window load and window resize.

```
$('.inside').css({
  'height': $('.border').outerHeight(),
  'overflow': 'hidden'
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/82ov0e3t/29/